# How can I create a "fuzzy crayon" effect?

Tags: shaders, particles

I spent sometime looking at [Media Molecule's Dreams](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qsCS8YH3rY). In it, the user is allowed to  fuzzy crayon strokes in the mid air (in 3D space)(at the point of the video around 43:00).

How can I implement a similar effect? Is it a polygon with texture or some complex particle system? I believe it have something to do shader but not sure how.

Comment: A quick look over the homepage doesn't show me any stills that appear to be the effect you're describing. Can you find a screenshot or video to link? I removed your second question about memory management; we prefer that you ask only a single question per post, and the question was too broad in any event.

Comment: For future reference linking Youtube video, if you right click the video, it gives the option to copy the video at the current time.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that you are talking about this:

[image]
There are two ways, that I can think of, with which one might achieve such an effect:

**1.** You could create a mesh made out of many connected cylinders, apply a texture to it like the one used in the example, and then use post-processing effects(like a bloom effect or a blur) to make it glow. Also, before each frame, you could add an offset to the uv texture coordinates of the mesh to make it look animated. The mesh can be created in a modeling program or you could create an algorithm the generates a mesh in real time.

or

**2.** You could have a list of nodes, where each node is connected with it's two neighboring nodes. These nodes will create a curve, around which you could have particles that slowly move from one node to the other. Also each particle could have a different speed so that it look more realistic.